# set layout manager in JApplet?

Tags: java

I've created a simple JApplet with three components, but the final added component always overlays the other two so that they are not visible.  I believe this is because they are being added to the same area in the default BorderLayout (correct me if I'm wrong!).  However, I keep getting an error message when I try to change the LayoutManager.  I commented on the line causing the problem below.

```
import javax.swing.*;   
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Vote extends JApplet {
  int candidate1 = 50; // this int holds the votes for candidate 1
  int candidate2 = 50; // this int holds the votes for candidate 2
  public void init() {
    JButton vote1 = new JButton("Vote for candidate 1");
    JButton vote2 = new JButton("Vote for candidate 2");
    JButton results = new JButton("See Results");
    vote1.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {         
        ++candidate1;
        String message = "You voted for candidate 1. \n\nThe current results are: \nCandidate 1: " + candidate1 + "\nCandidate 2: " + candidate2;
        String title = "Voting results";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      } 
    });
    vote2.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {         
        ++candidate2;
        String message = "You voted for candidate 2. \n\nThe current results are: \nCandidate 1: " + candidate1 + "\nCandidate 2: " + candidate2;
        String title = "Voting results";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      } 
    });
    results.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {         
        String message = "The current results are: \nCandidate 1: " + candidate1 + "\nCandidate 2: " + candidate2;
        String title = "Voting results";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      } 
    });
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));  // this line is the one I can't get to work
    getContentPane().add(vote1);
    getContentPane().add(vote2);
    getContentPane().add(results);
  }
}
```

Comment: What I always do is: Create a new `JPanel`, set its layout to whatever I want, add all the components to that JPanel and later add that JPanel to the frame / JApplet. *"I believe this is because they are being added to the same area in the default BorderLayout (correct me if I'm wrong!)"* You're correct on this

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Frakcool!  As it turns out, I forgot to import `java.awt.* `, but your solution is also a good one!